# Split array into 3 column

Tags: php, html

I have following code which is pulling record from database, I would like to split these records to 3 columns list. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php 

$values = get_field('hotel_facilities');

if($values)
{
    echo '<ul class="hotelpreferences2 left">';
    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        echo '<li class="' .$value.'">' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you researched/tried? Are you sure you want to do this in PHP and not by using proper CSS?

Comment: Hi Rudie, I googled and reached couple of solutions in stackoverflow but I didn't knew that I can solve this with css. I will try to find other solutions. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kingkero. Found it solution.

```
.hotelpreferences2 { 

-webkit-column-count: 3; 
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
```

}